# Jenkins mkdir permission issue in c drive while job running npm install WINDOW

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on my window machine. And created a job that will hit when anyone creates a pull request on bitbucket.

*I wanted to use the workspace created by Jenkins to make sure my build is running perfectly.*

When I try to run `npm install` in my working directory **C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\my_job** I am receiving permission denied error.

**EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dev.thespicetag.com\frontend\node_modules'**

> My Jenkin version is 2.222.1

I need a solution that will either changes my workspace directory or changes permission to the existing directory.

Comment: You can change permissions manually on your directory.  From explorer, right click on  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins' -> properties -> security.  It's pretty much self explanatory from there.

Comment: Okay! But it will be great if you can guide me on how I can switch Jenkins workspace directory from c drive to d drive.